# Error 1123: Filter operator not supported on type object

Tags: apache-flex, filter, operator-keyword

I have a a structure like this:

```
e.item.fatturato_ac_s1
e.item.fatturato_ac_s2
e.item.fatturato_ac_s3
e.item.fatturato_ac_s4
```

[...]
and so on...

in order to compute dinamically the string I wrote:

e.item.(myStr.toString()) where myStr (type string) = "fatturato_ac_s" + Index (so I can have fatturato_ac_s1, fatturato_ac_s2, ...)

I can correctly retrieve the value of e.item.(myStr.toString()) (a numeric value), but if I try to put it in a variable I get the error in the title:

```
myVariable = e.item.(myStr.toString())
```

myVariable is a Number.

I also tried:

```
myVariable = Number(e.item.(myStr.toString()))
```

but doesn't work... the same if I try String to String....

How can I solve it!?!!?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct syntax:

```
myVariable = Number(e.item[myStr])
```